# How to get only 7 days worth of data from a set date?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like this (see below), I have removed the majority of the columns and kept only those that require the operation:-

```
shortId Created_date    pid1    pid2    Game_Play_Date
abc 01-05-19    abc def 01-05-19
abc 01-05-19    abc pqr 01-05-19
abc 01-05-19    xyz abc 02-05-19
abc 01-05-19    qwe abc 03-05-19
abc 01-05-19    pqr abc 04-05-19
xyz 02-05-19    def xyz 02-05-19
xyz 02-05-19    pqr xyz 07-05-19
xyz 02-05-19    xyz pqr 07-05-19
xyz 02-05-19    xyz abc 15-05-19
xyz 02-05-19    xyz def 21-05-19
```

I need to get the data for 7 days from Created Date so if the ID has been created on 01.05.2019 I need the data till 07.05.2019 which would be given in Game_Play_Date column and so on.

I have tried slicing the data in 30 day parts but that is really confusing and not ideal.

The ideal result would be something like this (only 7 days worth of data depending on Game_Play_Date remains per shortId).

```
Created_date    shortId pid1    pid2    Game_Play_Date
01-05-19    abc abc def 01-05-19
01-05-19    abc abc pqr 01-05-19
01-05-19    abc xyz abc 02-05-19
01-05-19    abc qwe abc 03-05-19
01-05-19    abc pqr abc 04-05-19
02-05-19    xyz def xyz 02-05-19
02-05-19    xyz pqr xyz 07-05-19
02-05-19    xyz xyz pqr 07-05-19
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert both columns to datetimes and then subtract and compare days with [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) or by `Timedelta` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
cols = ['Created_date','Game_Play_Date']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)

df = df[df['Game_Play_Date'].sub(df['Created_date']).dt.days <=7]
#alternative
#df = df[df['Game_Play_Date'].sub(df['Created_date']) <=pd.Timedelta('7 days')]

print (df)
  shortId Created_date pid1 pid2 Game_Play_Date
0     abc   2019-05-01  abc  def     2019-05-01
1     abc   2019-05-01  abc  pqr     2019-05-01
2     abc   2019-05-01  xyz  abc     2019-05-02
3     abc   2019-05-01  qwe  abc     2019-05-03
4     abc   2019-05-01  pqr  abc     2019-05-04
5     xyz   2019-05-02  def  xyz     2019-05-02
6     xyz   2019-05-02  pqr  xyz     2019-05-07
7     xyz   2019-05-02  xyz  pqr     2019-05-07
```